# How far away was Admiral Ozzel from Darth Vader?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

As the title asks, how far away was Admiral Ozzel from Darth Vader during the Battle of Hoth in ***Empire Strikes Back***? Was he on another Star Destroyer? Or was he on the Super Star Destroyer? If Vader and Ozzel are on the same ship, where were they in relation to each other? The SSD is incredibly large, being 19,000 meters (11+ Miles) long!

Basically, how far away did Vader force choke this guy to death.

Comment: As I recall, the Admiral was on the closest ship to Hoth, Vader killed him because of that (the rebels spotted him and gave away that there were more Imperial ships coming). I don't recall where Vader was in relation though, or even if it was mentioned.

Comment: @CrowTRobot I'm rewatching ESB because of the Hoth recreation outside of my window, but the line about jumping too close meant that the entire fleet came in too close to Hoth-6, not just one ship. Admiral Ozzel ordered the entire fleet too close, for the surprise attack effect, not just one errant ship.

Answer (score 3):

Vader's hyperbaric meditation chamber is stated in various sources (for example, in Star Wars: Ultimate Blueprints, below) to be on the Executor. Given that Admiral Ozzel [commands the Executor](http://web.archive.org/web/20140302181851/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/characters/admiral-ozzel/) alongside his duties as Fleet Admiral, it stands to reason that they're **both on the same ship.**

As you've noted, this puts them no more than 11 miles apart but I'm unaware of any source that specifically states where the chamber is stored on board the Executor. I doubt it's *very far* from the Bridge if Vader has junior officers visiting him to pass on messages.

[image]